# Trying to read all the files in a folder on my own server via jquery

Tags: jquery, file

This is my own server so i *think* CORS should not apply.  I wish to be able to return a json string of all the filenames (or an array, at this point i don't care anymore) in a specific folder on my own server but it returns a 403 (Forbidden).

```
var imagesFolder = 'http://mywebsite.com/photos';

var dir = imagesFolder + "/" + country + "/" + cemetery;

var fileextension=".jpg";

  $.ajax({
     //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
        url: dir,
        success: function (data) {
            //Lsit all png file names in the page
            $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///","");               
                $("body").append($("<img src=" + Dir + filename + "></img>"));
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure javascript can't read files in a folder. You need another language like PHP to read the file names and printout the json you need to send it to your script.

Comment: ajax cross domain!? maybe try web crawler to file or jsonp.

Comment: if the website is ur, create api get photo, then ajax, like vyx.ca say.

Comment: Relying on the server to expose a browsable folder (I assume it's something similar to directory listing on apache) and then using JS to parse the output of that page is a bad idea. You are probably better of creating a server-side script that actually fetches the content of the directory, and returns that data (such as in JSON) to your JS, which it can then utilize.

Comment: I will attempt to use a server-side solution.